# PhantomJS ( vs nightwatch.js ) set cookie error

Tags: javascript, cookies, phantomjs, nightwatch.js

I found ( there are some issues and question at SO ) phantom.js cross-domains cookie problem.

So to fix this trouble I try next hack

```
  .getCookies(function callback(result) {
    var collectriumCookie = result.value[0];
    appCookie = {
      name     : collectriumCookie.name,
      domain: 'target.domain.com:5000',
      value    : collectriumCookie.value,
      expiry   : collectriumCookie.expire + 9999999
    };
    client.setCookie(appCookie);
  })
  .url('http://target.domain.com:5000/', function() {
    client.setCookie(appCookie);
  })
  .url('http://target.domain.com:5000/', function() {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(appCookie));
    client.setCookie(appCookie);
    client.getCookies(function(cookies) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(cookies))
    });
  })
```

I store cookie value at variable and set it for target subdomain ( I try with/ without port )

But debug message says:

```
{"name":"token","domain":"target.domain.com:5000","value":"2cb8f27ab0f0e19fe0f2076cde5bc82d5b6bb0ad148038a43c6945808e8210d64a2f062135f2bf59a580a4d3b9b207eda317aa3b413de951bd7d019feb5e1ec0","expiry":null}
{"sessionId":"f6e419ad-d848-423c-acd0-d7b153d0d64b","status":0,"state":"success","value":[{"name":"token","domain":".domain.com","secure":false,"path":"/","value":"","class":"org.openqa.selenium.Cookie","httpOnly":false,"hCode":110541305,"expiry":1428143377}],"class":"org.openqa.selenium.remote.Response","hCode":278799571}
```

cookie doesn't appply

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find answer. But trouble with cross-domain cookies was solved with PhantomJS v 2

At the moment there are some troubles with compiling so i spend about 5 minutes to find binaries